# Error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'XYZController'. Make sure controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

The following code works fine when executed from Visual Studio, but as I publish it and create a site in IIS to access it, I get the following error:

Code:

```
public class HelloController : ApiController
    {     

        public string HelloMethod()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

    }
```

Error:

```
An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of
type 'HelloController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public
constructor.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":" at
System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor
controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n at
System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has
occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
{A59E7747-3284-435B-8947-4E004361A6AC} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception
from HRESULT: 0x80040154
(REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).","ExceptionType":"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException","StackTrace":" at
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)\r\n at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean
publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)\r\n at
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)\r\n at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)\r\n at
GSWebAPI.Controller.GSConfigController..ctor()\r\n at lambda_method(Closure )\r\n at
System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor
controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"}}
At line:1 char:1
+ curl http://localhost:8080/api/Hello/HelloMethod
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no other constructors in that class? what about `GSConfig`?

Comment: Provide an actual representation of the controller.

Comment: Sorry, please ignore that. Have made the correction.

Comment: Without a [mcve] There is not much help that can be provided.

Comment: Are you using DI?

Comment: I believe your problem might lie around dependency resolutions... What kind of IOC container are you using? Maybe you forgot to register the build in resolver with it. 

// Register built in web api resolutions when creating http configuration
 config.DependencyResolver = new WebApiDependencyResolver(Container);

Read around here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh969049(v%3dvs.118)

Comment: @Nkosi not using DI, it's a very very basic controller

Comment: @KristófTóth there is no usage of DI it's very simple controller.

Comment: Can you please post your how you create your httpConfig?

Comment: @KristófTóth I have not created any httpConfig.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved now, only following was required. Thanks everyone for their inputs

Right click on the Application Pool and select Advanced settings - In General section set Enable 32 bit applications to True